# match two digits with colon

Tags: regex, bash

I want to match 2 digits like (30:02:40) resulted from file index.txt, but i am stuck on if condition, i don't know how to compare the result and do something.

**index.txt**

```
<tr><td>device</td> <td>10.10.10.1</td> <td>64232</td> <td>1</td> <td bgcolor=Red>30:02:40</td><tr>
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(cat index.txt |  sed -e 's/>/ /g;s/</ /g'| awk '{print $16}')
if [ $output == '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' ]; then
        echo "successful"
else
        echo "$output"
fi
```

tx

Comment: Not to overbeat the drum, but you might want to use an HTML parser here.

Comment: it's not overbeating, it's a CFG, you have to use a dedicated parser.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: it you know python, check out `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml`. otherwise, you get to figure out what libraries are available in your range of languages.

Comment: Using command line utilities, you can also have a look at `xmllint` with the `--html` option

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

- Single square bracket tests are not able to handle those kinds of wildcards, but you can use the extended test command with double brackets.
- Single-quote marks means that your wildcards are ignored and the string is treated as being verbatim.

With these two tweaks it works:

```
if [[ $output == [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] ]]; then
    echo "successful"
else
    echo "$output"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

[**xmlstarlet**](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html)/[**xmllint**](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) are the right tools for manipulating XML/HTML data.
(For xmlstarlet : the only requirement is that your content should be a valid HTML/XML document/fragment):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//tr/td[@bgcolor='Red']" -n \
<(sed -E 's/([^[:space:]=<>]+=)([^[:space:]=<>]+)/\1"\2"/g; s/<tr>$/<\/tr>/' index.txt)
```

The output:

```
30:02:40
```

---

**xmllint** approach:

```
xmllint --html --xpath "//tr/td[@bgcolor='Red']/text()" index.txt
30:02:40
```

Comment: Using `xmllint` with the `--html` flag should be better suited, because it allows to run `xpath` querries even on non-valid HTML files. In that case : `xmllint --html --xpath "string(//tr/td[@bgcolor='Red'])" file.html`

Answer (score 1):

why not do the matcing in `awk`, instead of just `{print $16}`

```
... | awk '$16~/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$/{print "successful"; exit} {print $16}'
```

you can also incorporate the first `sed` into this by just setting the right delimiters, but need to know the structure better to pinpoint the required field.

Answer (score -1):

Yes some html parser would be better, but a pure bash solution might be:

```
grep -oP "\d+:\d+:\d+" index.txt
```

Comment: this is not working on Solaris :))
"grep: illegal option -- o
grep: illegal option -- P
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . ."